# DVD's play, but only partly

Tags: 16.04, vlc, dvd

Using 16.04.1. DVD's won't play properly... i.e. some don't play at all, on one only the preview or trailer plays, but the full title or by-chapter version does not. The discs work on other DVD drives and computers.

I am having the same exact problem with two different DVD players; I purchased the second because I thought that the first one was a problem. The second is also a BluRay player.

Tried it with VLC media player, Dragonplayer, Xine, the standard one what's installed with 16.04.1... different notifications of course in different apps but in the end the same material doesn't play on both DVD players.

Comment: do you have libdvdcss installed?